# Embedding SWF file in WPF using Windows Forms Host?

Tags: wpf, flash, embed, shockwave

I'm currently in need of embedding an SWF file inside my WPF form. I read about it and there are at least two ways to accomplish this:

- Embedding the SWF inside an HTML file and embed the latter in my form.
- Embedding the SWF using the "AxShockwaveFlashObjects" assemblies. since this is meant to be used in WinForms and not in WPF, I will have to use a Windows Forms Host and put the Shockwave Flash Object inside of it.

Because of some of the requirements of my application (basically the "GetVariable" function of the shockwave object) I chose the second option. I put a Windows Forms Host in my WPF form, and put the following code in its constructor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AxShockwaveFlash flash = new AxShockwaveFlash();

        flash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        flash.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
        flash.Enabled = true;
        flash.Movie = "http://www.example.com/file.swf";

        windowsFormsHost1.Child = flash;
    }
```

But when I debug the code, I get this error on startup:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Flash_in_WPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '106'.

If I move that code to run when a button is clicked, I get a different error message:

> Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown.

Why am I getting these errors?

**Edit: solved it!** turns out I needed to move the whole initialization code to the "Grid_Loaded" event instead of in my ctor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I'm also trying to solve this problem; could you elaborate on how you solved it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can' t say I remember after two years. It seems I cut the code you see here in `MainWindow()` (except the `InitializeComponent()` invocation) and moved it somewhere else. Can you further explain what you are doing and what happens when you try what I tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved it**! Figured I should set the question as solved.

Turns out I needed to move the whole initialization code to the "Grid_Loaded" event instead of in my ctor.