# want to add swf file in wpf app! but this.Controls cant work..but already added in reference for it

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, flash

need help for codings..
currently developing a kinect game for my final year project..
wanted to add in the swf files in my wpf app for the splash page..
followed the instructions and put in reference..
but this.Controls got error..

[image: error]

added what i am asked to add..but i still have this error..

[image: error2]

one more thing..i cant find the AxHost2Components in my toolbox..and i am not sure how to add.. =(

[image: toolbox]

suppose to have this..but don't have.. anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

`Controls` is a WinForms property, not a WPF Window property. so if it's not finding a property `Controls` I think you may have a WPF app when you expected a WinForms app, or you may have a WPF app and you're using the wrong property.

I don't know about the missing AxHost2 Components in the ToolBox Window because I've never used those but if you've got yourself a WPF app instead of a WinForms app then maybe that's why it's not showing up?

FYI: [here's another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111165/embedding-swf-file-in-wpf-using-windows-forms-host) on how to embed SWF in your WPF app. Apparently the classes you are using are meant to be used with WinForms so I'm now assuming you set up a WPF project when you should have set up a WinForms project instead. that or you still have some work to do.

PS: there's some more text and code on how to do this in [this online readable book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=b1n3mOfdsBoC&pg=PA345&lpg=PA345&dq=wpf+axshockwaveflash+object&source=bl&ots=Ae9H3r3Kbn&sig=UXw8BZackdYwAWII5t_KakiSV-M&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=sr0kUNCBGYL80QXmtoDICg&ved=0CFkQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=wpf%20axshockwaveflash%20object&f=false) (you may need to scroll up a bit, hope that stuff will help you).